# error when translating a df in python with google_trans_new library

Tags: python, time, google-translate

I have the following code to translate df columns, the code works without problem with a small data set, but when I apply it to a df with a greater number of data I get the following error:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()
    


df['artists'] = df['artists'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x))
df



google_new_transError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: timeout
```

Previously I had the error

```
429 (too many requests) from the TTS API. Probable cause: unknown
```

I know that when making several requests the IP address is temporarily blocked but I do not know how I could solve it

Answer (score 0):

Since **google_trans_new** still uses google translate at the back end, you will constantly encounter this error. You can increase the [timeout parameter](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new#translate-1) to reduce the number of request you send in an hour and be inside the [hourly limit](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/15027713/when-i-am-calling-google-translate-api-multiple-times-in-my-program-it-is-showing-error-why-is-it-so?hl=en&msgid=15147904).

But I highly suggest that if you will be using the translation feature heavily, consider using the paid [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate). As the API will process your request in a timely manner and you won't be worrying much on request limits.